# Wordpress Clean URLs show "Page Not Found"

Tags: wordpress, core, urls

Edited my civicrm.settings.php file to enable clean URL's (as described in https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/wordpress/clean-urls/)
It does not work and any time I try to go to a clean URL page I get the standard wordpress "nothing found page"

Comment: FYI for anyone coming to this page looking for info on WordPress Clean URLs - documentation has moved to https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/wordpress/clean-urls/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check that you the base page here: https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/setting/uf&reset=1

The value here

[image]

Should be an existing published WP Page.

I would then revisit the permalinks page.

That should 'fix' it.

Comment: Thank you.
That should be added to the instructions page as Civicrm already creates a WP /civicrm